# Is it possible to change the parameters that a predefined method can take in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, casting

Im not sure if this is possible. Im using a method that takes the parameter int but i found myself in a situation where i need to be able to use a float value. Does anyone know if there is anyway to change the parameters that a predefined method can take?

Thanks All
Best
Alex

Comment: Have you tried overloading the method?

Comment: Just cast it to int with (int), or write your own wrapper around it that takes in the float, and casts to an int internally.

Comment: Thanks everyone ! I learned a lot today. All the best

Answer (score 0):

C# has generics for his type of requirement, where you want to apply a logic indifferent of the type of parameter input

for example :

```
T foo<T>(T param)
{
    return param + 1;
}

//and it can be used  like this 

int i;
foo<int>(i); // return type is int

float f;
foo<float>(f); // return type is float
```

Comment: Thanks so much this was really helpful! when i get a rep of 15 ill give you all up votes.  Best Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can overload a method as follows:

```
public static float myMethod(float sumNumber)
{ 
      // whatever you need for code here
      return sumNumber;
}

public static int myMethod(int sumNumber)
{ 
     // whatever you need for code here
     return sumNumber;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't those 2 methods have the same return type?

Comment: @Jules I'm not sure I follow either way we are returning the float or int I just didn't add any logic on the calculation.

Comment: @Jules There's no requirement that they must.

Comment: Thanks so much this was really helpful! when i get a rep of 15 ill give you all up votes.  Best Alex

Answer (score 0):

> Member overloading means creating two or more members on the same type that differ only in the number or type of parameters but have the same name. - *[Microsoft MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229029(v=vs.110).aspx)*

```
// your method
public static double Inc(int i)
{
     return i + 1;
}

// your method (overloaded)
public static double Inc(double d)
{
    return d + 1;
}

int i = Inc(3);
double d = Inc(2.0); // You can use the same method with different parameter types
```

The website [www.dotnetperls.com](https://www.dotnetperls.com) has a lot of nice examples. If you want to see another explanation besides MSDN, you may read [this](https://www.dotnetperls.com/overload).

Comment: Thanks so much this was really helpful! when i get a rep of 15 ill give you all up votes.  Best Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can define a generic class for such methods.

```
public class GenericMethodsClass<T>
{
    public static T myMethod(T sumNumber)
    {
        // whatever you need for code here
        return sumNumber;
    }
}
```

Calling:

```
GenericMethodsClass<int>.myMethod(1);
GenericMethodsClass<double>.myMethod(1.2);
```

Comment: Thanks so much this was really helpful! when i get a rep of 15 ill give you all up votes.  Best Alex

Comment: Now u can do that